# count properties in a class that follow a specific naming convention

Tags: c#

In a project, there is a class which has several property names that are similar.  The properties of interest begin with `ReportData`.  Is there a way to modify the `GetReportDataFieldCount` method so it automatically counts the number of properties in the class that begin with `ReportData`?

```
public class ReportRowDataContract
{   
    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData1 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData2 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData3 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData4 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData5 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData6 { get; set; }

    // an indexed property - for accessing report data fields by index
    public ReportDataDataContract this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReportDataDataContract[]
            {
              ReportData1,
              ReportData2,
              ReportData3,
              ReportData4,
              ReportData5,
              ReportData6                  
            }[i];
        }
    }

    public int GetReportDataFieldCount()
    {
        return 6;
    }        
}
```

Note that I cannot change the structure of this class (ie. sequentially numbered ReportData properties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection. Specifically, [`GetProperties()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperties) to get an array of [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties) - and from that it's just linq's [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__):

```
int GetReportDataPropertiesCount()
{
    return typeof(ReportRowDataContract)
        .GetProperties()
        .Count(p => p.Name.StartsWith("ReportData"));
}
```